# Generating android build with jenkins.Creating .apk files

Tags: android, jenkins, apk

I am using Jenkins for continuous integration of android apps on mac.But i am unable to generate .apk file with Jenkins same as we create .ipa in iOS apps.what will be the configuration to create .apk file for distribution on mac.

Comment: Why are you unable to create APK files? What have you tried?

Comment: I dont know how to create apk. building ipa is very simple by selecting the checkbox.
i was trying to create apk by using 'ant scripts' "ant release" command in 'execute shell' 
I was googling from a very long time but didn't find anything helpful and still unable to create apk. ;(
if You have any idea of creating apk.Please share.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

You can generate both release and debug builds in jenkins. For that, please follow the below procedure.

1. Launch the job/project configuration screen by clicking on configure button which is available left side panel of job/project dashboard.
2. Scroll down to see the **Build** section.
3. Click on **"Add Build step"** button to see the drop down list.
4. Click on **"Invoke Ant"** item in that and do like same available in attached screen shot.
5. Save these modifications by clicking on save button when you have completely done the 4th step above.
6. Click on **Build Now** button which is available at top left side panel.
7. Now you have got the builds in your jenkins workspace. 
   **Ex:** In my case, builds are generated in the below path.
   **C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\JOB_NAME\bin**

You can also see the builds on Job dashboard by enabling the artifacts like below.

1. Scroll down to see the **Post-build Actions** section.
2. Click on **"Add post-build action"** button to see the drop down list.
3. Click on **"Archive the artifacts"**, and this will add one item in Post build actions section.
4. Give the path and extension of which files you need to display in artifacts section of dashboard. 
   Ex: **/bin/*.apk** - to display all the apk files available in bin folder of that job.[image]

Comment: no revision recorded for svn://ws403017/mobilerepos/android/POC/POD in the previous build
FATAL: Unable to find build script at /Users/macbookpro/.jenkins/jobs/Android_test/workspace/build.xml
Build step 'Invoke Ant' marked build as failure

I've followed your steps..but i'm getting this error.. @noundla