# how to generate signed wear apk with jenkins without copying it to under handheld project

Tags: android, jenkins, apk, wear-os

I want to generate and run wear apk with jenkins. In www.developer.android.com, it is named "package manually".

But I don't want to copy my wear apk to under handheld project. I want this operation processes automatically, not manually.

link: https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/packaging.html#PackageManually

How can I fix this problem?

Thank you advance.

Comment: Have you tried reading this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-build-android-apps-with-jenkins)? also, check this related SO ticket: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21570038/generating-android-build-with-jenkins-creating-apk-files

Comment: Thank you @d.datul1990, but I'm actually asking for android-wear apk

Comment: Have you tried this? https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/packaging.html